# Shopware 6 partitioning

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Has anyone had any experience with database partitioning? We already have a lot of data and queries on it are already starting to slow down. Maybe someone has some examples? These are tables related to orders.

Answer (score 2):

Shopware, since version `6.4.12.0`, allows the use of database clusters, see the [relevant documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/database-cluster). You will have to set up a number read-only nodes first. The load of reading data will then be distributed among the read-only nodes while write operations are restricted to the primary node.

Note that in a cluster setup you should also use a [lock storage](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/lock-store) that compliments the setup.

Comment: `Lock storage` should be used when you use multiple webservers, the number of db servers does not matter.

Comment: Yea we have it. We need more optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using a DB cluster you can also try to reduce the load of the db server.

The first thing you should enable the [HTTP-Cache](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/framework/http_cache), still better to additionaly also set up a [reverse cache](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/reverse-http-cache) like varnish. This will greatly decrease the number of requests that hit your webserver and thus your DB server as well.

Besides all those measures explained here should improve the overall performance of your shop as well as decreasing load on the DB.

Additionally you could use [Elasticsearch](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/elasticsearch), so that costly search requests won't hit the Database. And use a "real" [MessageQueue](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/message-queue), so that the messages are not stored in the Database. And use Redis instead of the database for the storage of performance critical information as is documented in the articles in this [category of the official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance).

The impact of all those measures probably depends on your concrete project setup, so maybe you see in the DB locks something that hints to one of the points i mentioned previously, so that would be an indicator to start in that direction. E.g. if you see a lot of search related queries Elasticsearch would be a great start, but if you see a lot of DB load coming from writing/reading/deleting messages, then the MessageQueue might be a better starting point.

All in all when you use a DB cluster with a primary and multiple replicas and use the additional services i mentioned here your shop should be able to scale quite well without the need for partitioning the actual DB.

Comment: Yea. We have it also. We still need more optimization.